# Designing Workflow to Send Alerts Help please

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a list app with columns: Title, Issue, Staff, Action. It needs to send an email to manager when a new title and issue is added. She then needs to modify the item to assign this to Staff to report on Action, then an email should be sent to the staff. The staff then modify the item to put in the action then an email will be sent to the manager.

I have done this:

```
Stage:Starting process
Email Manager
Set Workflow Status to Started
If modified by Manager
    Email Staff
Set Workflow Status to Email to report on action taken sent to Staff
If modified by Current Item:Staff
    Email Manager
Set Workflow Status to Action reported back by ward manager
```

Transition to stage
    Go to End of Workflow

ANd it's not working.

Any advise, please.

Comment: What a type of field "Staff" ?

Comment: person or group

Comment: Where is it failing? Have you tried just having it email you to make sure the email is being fired?